# allow remote access without port forwarding

Tags: remote

I need to be able to remotely access a database on a device. It works fine when it is the last hop (i.e. it has it's own public IP). Now I need to make it work within a local WiFi as well. (i.e. Internet -> Router -> device).
I do not have access to the router and therefore cannot forward any ports.

Is this possible or do I need to make configurations to the router?

Comment: In any case we are going to need a lot more information about your setup

Answer (score 4):

It's possible via services like hamachi (unsure if still exists) or teamviewer has a private vpn feature. Essentially what you need to do is run a piece of software on your server that calls out to a third party service, and your connecting machine uses the same service. That's one way to gain access without configuration of Port forwarding. There are other ways, this is probably best put as a networking question rather than a database question.

Comment: Alternatively, it should be possible to do this using a proxy like [localtunnel](https://superuser.com/questions/1315504/self-hosting-without-access-to-router).